# Finding source code of R packages and potentially making changes

Tags: r, package

I would like to find and read the source code of an R package. Let's say I would like to find purrr and figure out the difference between map_chr() and find out if it is using lapply().

purrr directory has the following files:

```
DESCRIPTION INDEX       LICENSE     Meta        NAMESPACE   NEWS.md     R           doc         help        html        libs
```

I know that purrr has a github repository and that is it also on CRAN. But am not able to find out where its functions are defined. Should I do this within R? And if necessary make changes there? What if some package has some parts written in C or Python?

For example, purrr has .libs/purrr.so which I assume is compiled C code. Where exactly is map_chr() defined within purrr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the R code is written under `R` folder. For example, `map_chr` is present at https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/R/map.R#L187

which defines it as

```
map_chr <- function(.x, .f, ...) {
  .f <- as_mapper(.f, ...)
  .Call(map_impl, environment(), ".x", ".f", "character")
}
```

where `map_impl` is a C function defined at https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/src/map.c#L60

Comment: Thanks! How about the base package? lapply()

Comment: @user171558 `lapply` is at https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/lapply.R#L19